# Implementing third party Android libraries into Nativescript Plugins?

Tags: android, ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I was looking to put in a third party Android package, like https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer
On android, you can add the dependencies to the build.gradle ...

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.X.X'
```

How do you do the same to a nativescript-angular plugin?
Now I do understand that you can do this by making your own android project, with a jar file as given in https://www.nativescript.org/blog/plugins-and-jars ... But this isn't the option to be able to do the same for android as well as ios.

Comment: Try adding it in plugin/platforms/Android/include.gradle

Comment: There is already an [exoplayer plugin](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-exoplayer/) for NativeScript, did you try that. May be you can take a fork the repo if you want to add any missing features.

Comment: @Manoj It's specifically a video player, for angular. I needed it for HLS adaptive  streaming But yes. Thanks for the idea! :D